# Create cocos2dx plugin-x for 3rd party SDK

Tags: android, plugins, cocos2d-x

I have a problem with create plugin for 3rd party SDK with plugin-x for android.
Then launch publish.sh to create got this java error:

```
cocos2d/plugin/plugins/platform101xp_sdk/proj.android/src/org/cocos2dx/plugin/platformXP.java:16: error: cannot find symbol    
public class platformXP implements InterfacePlatformXP
        [javac]                                    ^
        [javac]   symbol: class InterfacePlatformXP
        [javac] cocos2d/plugin/plugins/platform101xp_sdk/proj.android/src/org/cocos2dx/plugin/platformXP.java:43: error: package PlatformXPWrapper does not exist
```

All needed files placed to correct folders, java package one for all - org.cocos2dx.plugin
All another plugins compilled fine.
Need any assistance.